# SSRS: Passing different parameter values to stored procedure for two Data Sets

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables in my Report. Both use two separate Data Sets, which get data from the same Stored Procedure. Now, I want the data sets to get different data based on different parameter values. Is there a way to achieve that? I am using SQL Server 2008-R2. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the Report Data screen (Ctrl+Alt+D), you can tie both datasets up to different parameters.

1. Add your parameters
2. Open up the Datasets properties
3. Go to the parameters section
4. Add the required parameter and give it a name the same as your Stored Proc parameter e.g. @EmployeeId

providing the query is marked as type "Stored Procedure" (in query section), this will pass the parameter over on selection.  Repeat the process for the other dataset